# How can I add new objects to FormAlchemy's Grid

Tags: sqlalchemy, formalchemy

I'd like to implement an "add row" button on some of my FormAlchemy grid forms to create objects.

Reading through the source it would appear that there isn't this functionality at present so wondered if there's another project that does it, or if anyone has any pointers on how to do it?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is fa.query - formalchemy jquery library/integration.  http://www.mail-archive.com/pylons-discuss@googlegroups.com/msg14228.html

Appreciate that this may be too late for you as you asked this over a year ago.